# Keyboard layout keys aren't maintained on debian

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

So I'm not sure if I should be posting this here, but: 
I'm on Debian Jessie with xfce4 as desktop manager and I have US and GR keyboard layouts. On the 'keyboard layout' settings window I select Alt+Shift as hotkeys, but I find that on restart the setting isn't maintained. I don't save the session so that shouldn't be problem right?

I currently have a workaround:Run this as a script `setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle us,il`  on start up.

My question is why are the keys not remaining as hotkeys on startup?